# Confused about anti-fermion notation

Tags: field-theory, second-quantization, charge-conjugation

Classically anti-fields are obtained by charge conjugation, right? But sometimes authors label hermitian conjugated fields as anti-particles (or barred fields in Dirac language). But h.c. and charge conjugation differ by ($\pm i\sigma_2$).

Is it because after quantization, hermitian conjugated operators become anti-particle creation operators?